# Android setting label to spinner

Tags: android

Hi 
  how to set a label in spinner: ie the lable should initially visible when user clicke the spinner button options visible , when user select the option the label should replace with the new item,is it possible with spinner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Spinners` do not have "labels". Beyond that, though, what I think you are describing is exactly what a `Spinner` does:

- When closed, shows the last selection made by the user, or the initial selection if it has never been opened
- When opened, shows a selection list of available choices for the user

Comment: Ware , actually i want to set some labels instead of the default value.

Comment: Now i done this by using a button and dialog box,i interested to know that is it possible with the spinner

Answer (score 2):

You can put your first item as a label:

```
<string-array name="countriesList">
    <item>(Select country)</item>
    <item>Country 1</item>
    <item>Country 2...</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in this way:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(phonePrefix != null && phonePrefix.getAdapter() != null)
            {
                TextView txt = (TextView) phonePrefix.getSelectedView();
                String str = txt.getText().toString();
                String [] arr = str.split(" ");
                str  = arr[1] + " " + arr[2];
                txt.setText(str);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. I would be doing it in following way:

1. Inflate Button with desired text/label
2. Intercept button pressing
3. Create on-fly Spinner
4. Replace Button with Spinner
5. Be happy