# Retrieving data from firebase in different spinners of different categories

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I am developing an e-commerce android application and I am using Firebase real-time database. I have different categories of products(e-g buttons, laces, gowns etc.) I want to display my products in different spinners according to their categories like all the buttons in my database comes under spinner named 'buttons' and all the gowns in my database comes under spinner named 'gowns' and so on. What i have done so far is to show all my products in a single spinner. Now i want to do as explained above. Here is code of what i have done so far.
[Here is the look of my database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST73d.png)

```
 private Spinner spinner;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customization);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    showDataSpinner();
}

private void showDataSpinner()
{
    databaseReference.child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            arrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                arrayList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomizationActivity.this, R.layout.style_spinner, arrayList);
            spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: it works totally fine..but if you look up the database picture i attached i want all my products to show in different spinners according to their different categories.

Comment: In this code it show all my products in a single spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you make a collection per spinner? This would be the fastest solution for a front-end to retrieve data. But this might also impact other parts of your program as well. Take look at [Create data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout)

```
databaseReference.child("Products")
```

becomes

```
databaseReference.child("ProductsOfCategoryGowns")
```

and

```
databaseReference.child("ProductsOfCategoryButtons")
```

### An easy sub-optimal solution

The easiest change to your current code would be to add something like an if statement in the for-loop.

```
for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
  if(item.child("category").getValue(String.class) === 'Buttons") {
    arrayList.add(item.child("pname").getValue(String.class));
  }
}
```

Where "Buttons" is the requested value for the `category` property.

### Firestore

Changing to Firestore migth also be worth a consideration. Then you can do something like

```
db.collection("Products").where("category", "==", "Buttons")
```

to retrieve the products of category Buttons. In stead of loading all products from the server and then only display a portion.

Comment: thank you so much it worked for me. is there any way i can set a title for spinner like for buttons spinner "Buttons" is displayed on that spinner. i dont know why setPrompt is not working

Comment: Well, that is a different question.
I don't know about spinner, but I guess that setPrompt shows a string when the spinner is empty, otherwise the spinner is showing one item. Something like a label would be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334684/android-setting-label-to-spinner